# In Vue3, how to check value of each radio button checked from a single group of radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, vuejs3

I have just started training with Vue3 and really like it a lot. But I am stuck at some issues which seemed much easier (intuitive) with vanilla JS.

I have this group of radio buttons which have same `name` value

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inputs">
      <div class="input">
        <input
          id="01-01"
          v-model="voted"
          type="radio"
          name="VP-01"
          @change="showCheckedValue"
        />
        <label for="01-01">1</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input">
        <input
          id="01-02"
          v-model="voted"
          type="radio"
          name="VP-01"
          @change="showCheckedValue"
        />
        <label for="01-02">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <input
          id="01-03"
          v-model="voted"
          type="radio"
          name="VP-01"
          @change="showCheckedValue"
        />
        <label for="01-03">3</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input">
        <input
          id="01-04"
          v-model="voted"
          type="radio"
          name="VP-01"
          @change="showCheckedValue"
        />
        <label for="01-04">4</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <input
          id="01-05"
          v-model="voted"
          type="radio"
          name="VP-01"
          @change="showCheckedValue"
        />
        <label for="01-05">5</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="checked">
      <div class="one">Checked value of 1 : {{ voted }}</div>
      <div class="one">Checked value of 2 : {{ voted }}</div>
      <div class="one">Checked value of 3 : {{ voted }}</div>
      <div class="one">Checked value of 4 : {{ voted }}</div>
      <div class="one">Checked value of 5 : {{ voted }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="voted">
      {{ voted }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am able to output the value with v-model and that's fine... and I can also get the checked value for CSS styling... so that's fine..

But when one input field (radio button) is checked then I would assume that the `ON` value for that button defines the status (Maybe I am wrong in this assumption)... but in my code if I click on any button it converts to `ON` but the other buttons too stay as `ON`.. I would assume that if the button is checked then it would be `ON` and if not then it would be ... maybe `null`? or `false`? I am not sure...

I have added a show `showCheckedValue` function to be called `@change` but didn't know how to make it work...

Here's my script and styles setup to test... I even tried to change the `v-model= "voted"` to have a different one for each button like `v-model="voted1"` and `v-model="voted2"` and so on.. but that didn't work either..

So here's the question
**How do I output or replicate the checked value of a group of radio buttons? If one of them is checked it should be `true` or `on` and the others should be `false` or `null`?**

Here's a link to my test on codepen.. https://codepen.io/alimbolar/pen/OJvmNQB

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const voted = ref(null);
// const voted2 = ref(null);
// const voted3 = ref(null);
// const voted4 = ref(null);
// const voted5 = ref(null);
</script>

<!-- Use preprocessors via the lang attribute! e.g. <style lang="scss"> -->
<style>
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#app {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 50px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inputs {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.checked {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.checked > * {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.voted {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a `value` for each `radio button` so the `voted ref` can bind with it.

[Please check the codepen](https://codepen.io/mena234/pen/LYdyZWB)

Comment: thanks @Mina ... it seems to work.. but I had a question... the values being passed to radioStatus as arguments seem to be hard-coded.. if I had each input as a component where the input is part of a `card` I would need a dynamic value... can we manage this?

Comment: Yes for sure, it just made it dynamic, please visit the link again.

Comment: When you click on one radio button there is surely a change in the current button.. but is there a change event on the button that was checked and now has lost its checked status? Also the other 3 buttons where nothing changed, is there a change event there? I am just trying to get my head around this to understand it properly..

Comment: Thanks @Mina for the dynamic option..:-).. it looks good.. I'll have a proper look at ti and confirm ..

Comment: so just to understand it properly, your `voted` variable has to be in the parent component of which each `input` is a child component.. am I right?.. I was trying to do it in my other app, by having the `voted` variable in the `input` child component and was trying to emit to get the status of `voted` but your approach seems more logical and the movement of the `voted` variable is from parent to child.. but do let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: `so just to understand it properly, your voted variable has to be in the parent component of which each input is a child component.. am I right?` Yes, exactly.

Comment: can you please help me with this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73063744/in-vue3-how-to-convert-nested-proxy-objects-reactive-data-to-regular-objects