# In Vue3, how to convert Nested Proxy Objects (Reactive data) to regular objects?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

I have a pinia store that has a user object..

```
export const useStore = defineStore('store', {
  state: () => ({
    currentSlide: 1,
    user: {},
    data,
  }),
})
```

I am then updating it to have a an array `vote`  inside the user object

And then the vote array has multiple objects as votes.. so I have the array as a `user.vote` which then is in this format `[{vote:01},{vote:02}.{vote:3}]`

I need to push this array to mongodb.. but when I try to access this array, as it's reactive data, it's a Proxy Object with multiple Proxy Objects inside of it..

So I tried `toRaw(user.vote)` (not sure if this is the right approach) and the array was no longer a Proxy but a regular array.. however the objects (votes) inside of it are still Proxy Objects..

How do I get a regular array with regular objects from this pinia structure to send to mongodb?

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71075490/how-to-make-a-structuredclone-of-a-proxy-object and I used structuredClone and it works!.. but would appreciate to have some advise on whether it's the right way to do this.. or if there's another way..

Comment: What is the problem with calling `JSON.stringify(user.vote)`? MongoDB stores JSON values.

Comment: @IVOGELOV : you are absolutely right!.. I guess I am guilty of 'overthinking the problem'... I just assumed that maybe Proxy Object is a complicated format and would need something complicated to 'decrypt'..;-).. thanks for simplifying it for me... I needed it to be an object so I just did `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user.vote))` and it worked perfect..:-)..

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript version:

```
import { isReactive, toRaw } from 'vue'

export function isObject (value: unknown): boolean {
  return value !== null && !Array.isArray(value) && typeof value === 'object'
}

export function getRawData<T>(data: T): T {
  return isReactive(data) ? toRaw(data) : data
}

export function toDeepRaw<T>(data: T): T {
  const rawData = getRawData<T>(data)

  for (const key in rawData) {
    const value = rawData[key]

    if (!isObject(value) && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      continue
    }

    rawData[key] = toDeepRaw<typeof value>(value)
  }

  return rawData // much better: structuredClone(rawData)
}
```

JavaScript version:

```js
import { isReactive, toRaw } from 'vue'

export function isObject (value) {
  return value !== null && !Array.isArray(value) && typeof value === 'object'
}

export function getRawData (data) {
  return isReactive(data) ? toRaw(data) : data
}

export function toDeepRaw (data) {
  const rawData = getRawData(data)

  for (const key in rawData) {
    const value = rawData[key]

    if (!isObject(value) && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      continue
    }

    rawData[key] = toDeepRaw(value)
  }

  return rawData // much better: structuredClone(rawData)
}
```

with Nuxt.js 3, add these helpers in a file to the `utils/` folder for auto-imports.

Answer (score 1):

What if you clone the data and send the clone to the DB? That's what I usually do:

`const cloneToSendToMongoDB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user.vote)`

or use lodash cloneDeep which is a little more readable than above:

```
// install lodash if you don't have it
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep' 

const cloneToSendToMongoDB = cloneDeep(user.vote)
```

***Warning:***
Don't get excited and think, oh we are cloning stuff, so I can use the cool new `structuredClone` method for this, it will not unwrap the nested proxies unfortunately, only the outermost proxy. The first two methods above will unwrap everything.